# What does "quite a ride" mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw the following sentence in an article.

> It's now been a year since I joined Microsoft and I have to say, it's been quite a ride.
> What does "quite a ride" mean? Does it mean very successful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"quite a ride" is a reference to getting off a rollercoaster. There have been a lot of memorable, intense up and downs during the ride.

The implication can vary - it might have been fun, or it could have been scary, unpredictable, sickening, etc. The rest of the text should go on and explain what is meant.